# PayPal Rest-API PHP - Blank Page

Tags: php, paypal

I am having trouble with the PayPal PHP Rest API.

For some reason it shows as a blank page and only shows info through puTTY. I have no idea what's going on.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

$api = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        'yes it is correct',     // ClientID
        'correct '      // ClientSecret
    )
);
$api->setConfig([
'mode' => 'sandbox',
'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
'log.LogEnabled' => false,
'log.FileName' => '',
'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
'validation.level' => 'log'

]);


$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");



$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice(7.5);
$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setName('Granola bars')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(5)
    ->setPrice(2);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));



$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping(1.2)
    ->setTax(1.3)
    ->setSubtotal(17.50);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("USD")
    ->setTotal(20)
    ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription("Payment description")
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());




$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("http://uplayeve.ml/PayPal/ExecutePayment.php?success=true")
    ->setCancelUrl("http://uplayeve.ml/PayPal//ExecutePayment.php?success=false");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$request = clone $payment;


try {
    $payment->create($api);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Maybe an error or something';
    exit(1);
}

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

ResultPrinter::printResult("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", "<a href='$approvalUrl' >$approvalUrl</a>", $request, $payment);

return $payment;
    ?>
```

Also here is my current `phpinfo()`: http://uplayeve.ml/PayPal/phpinfo.php

Comment: is all your error reporting turned on?

Comment: Yes it is - It doesn't work through Web it only works with puTTy. Every other PHP file I have works.

Comment: Try removing ResultPrinter::printResult line from the code, and see if it works. The code is only for sample, and I have added that comment just now to all the sample pages to remove confusion. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

A Blank Page generally in PHP means, something threw an error, but your reporting is not enabled. You could easily enable this by adding these two lines at the top.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

This should potentially print the error now. Also, there are few things you should note.

1. `ResultPrinter` is a sample only code. Please disregard that, and remove that from your code. That could be causing the error.
2. If for any reason, you wish to catch and read proper exception, add this catch method as shown below.

   ```
   try {
       $payment->create($api);
   } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
       echo $ex->getData();
   }
   ```

Btw, we are adding more and more samples, wiki pages, source docs, etc at http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/ to enable developers to integrate with REST API faster.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: creditCard in /var/www/PayPal/payment.php on line 89

Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in /var/www/PayPal/payment.php on line 89

Comment: Hey Haroon, I have updated the try catch block. What I meant was to add a catch block for `PayPalConnectionException` that will give you a detailed message in `$ex->getData()`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that! So what do I need to update on the code that will make it work?

Comment: Hey haroon, I could help you resolve the errors you are seeing, however, it is the debugging that is required. If you followed the above steps, you should be able to resolve the blank page issue. Also, I am seeing that you are not echoing anything on your code. I would recommend adding `echo $payment->toJSON()` at the end, to print the object.

Comment: Hi sorry for bugging you Jay, But I am getting this error {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/PayPal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php on line 45

Comment: That error means, that you dont have the client credentials provided properly. Happens, when your credentials for some reason are not set correctly. Can you please verify the logs to see if it is sending the Auth code properly ?